# What is the bare minimum I need to write in Win32 to get a Window to open?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, graphics, window

## Question:

I am trying to set up the Winapi with C to display a simple window with the bare minimum of code, how do I do that in the way that my source code is formatted?

## Issue:

The following does not open a window, it simply closes, why is this?

---

```
/* window_s.h */
typedef struct {
        WNDCLASS wc;                                                                     
        HINSTANCE hInstance;
        HWND hwnd;
} WINDOW;
```

---

```
/* setUpWinProc.h */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND hwnd,
        UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam) { }
```

---

```
/* registerWindow.c */
void registerWindow(WINDOW *window) {
        const char CLASS_NAME[]
                = "Window Class Name";
        window->wc.lpfnWndProc  = WindowProc;
        window->wc.hInstance    = window->wc.hInstance;
        window->wc.lpszClassName        = CLASS_NAME;
        RegisterClass(&(window->wc));
}
```

---

```
/* createWindow.c */
int_fast64_t CreateWindow_(WINDOW *window) {
        window->hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
                0,              // Optional window styles
                window->wc.lpszClassName,       // Window class
                "Window",       // Window text
                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,    //Window style

                // Size and position
                CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

                NULL,   // Parent window
                NULL,   // Menu
                window->hInstance,      // Instance handle
                NULL            // Additional application data
                );
        if (window->hwnd == NULL)
                return 0;
        return window->hwnd;
}
```

---

```
/* Window_Main.c */
#include <windows.h>
#include "window_s.h"
#include "setUpWinProc.h"
#include "registerWindow.c"
#include "createWindow.c"
#include <stdio.h>
int WINAPI WinMain ( HINSTANCE hInstance,
                        HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                        LPSTR pCmdLine,
                        int nCmdShow ) {
        WINDOW window = {{}, hInstance};
        registerWindow(&window);
        CreateWindow_(&window);
        ShowWindow(window.hwnd, nCmdShow);
}
```

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is explained by several thousand tutorials and examples all over the Internet. Please be more specific about your problem, [edit] your question to give us more details as well as a [mre].

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: A `WindowProc` that exhibits undefined behavior is rarely a good start. Once that is fixed you'll need to dispatch messages on the thread that owns the window. [Get Started with Win32 and C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows) serves as a good reference.

Comment: Microsoft has a tutorial on MSDN that directly answers your question: [Module 1. Your First Windows Program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program): "*In this module, we will write **a minimal Windows desktop program**. All it does is create and show a blank window.*" For future reference, please do some research before asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

This is part of the issue:

```
int WINAPI WinMain ( HINSTANCE hInstance,
                        HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                        LPSTR pCmdLine,
                        int nCmdShow ) {
        WINDOW window = {{}, hInstance};
        registerWindow(&window);
        CreateWindow_(&window);
        ShowWindow(window.hwnd, nCmdShow);
}
```

What do you think happens after `ShowWindow` returns and `WinMain` itself returns?  (Hint: the program exits).

Extend your WinMain to **pump messages** with TranslateMessage+DispatchMessage.

```
int WINAPI WinMain ( HINSTANCE hInstance,
                        HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                        LPSTR pCmdLine,
                        int nCmdShow ) {

        MSG msg;

        WINDOW window = {{}, hInstance};
        registerWindow(&window);
        CreateWindow_(&window);
        ShowWindow(window.hwnd, nCmdShow);

        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
}
```

Then your message proc needs to handle WM_CLOSE and WM_PAINT as a minimum and be able to forward to the default window proc for messages it doesn't handle.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND hwnd,
        UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam) {

    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_PAINT: {
    
             PAINTSTRUCT ps;
             BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
             EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
             break;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }

        default: {
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Your RegisterClass call looks suspicous as well. Let's initialize like this:

```
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex = {0};
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WindowProc;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;

    RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
```

If you have Visual Studio (and edition), there's a default Win32 application that generates the most minimal of stub applications that does exactly what you are trying to achieve.  Look for the C++ project for "Default Windows Application" or similar.

Comment: *"your message proc needs to handle WM_CLOSE and WM_PAINT as a minimum"* - It does not. Forwarding **all** message to `DefWindowProc` (and **returning a value**) is sufficient.

Comment: *"Your RegisterClass call looks suspicous as well."* - It doesn't. It passes in a fully initialized `WNDCLASS` structure, so there's nothing that needs to be fixed. I will argue, though, that *"here, write some **more** code!"* won't make for a good answer when the question is *"What is the bare minimum I need to write?"*.

Comment: Small nitpick - `PostQuitMessage()` should be called in response to `WM_DESTROY` (the [`PostQuitMessage()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postquitmessage) even says so), not `WM_CLOSE`.  The default handler for `WM_CLOSE` will call `DestroyWindow()`, but the default handler for `WM_DESTROY` does nothing.

Comment: @IInspectable - Without WM_DESTROY being handled, the window would close, but not post a quit message. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: That's correct, but ending a program isn't part of the *"bare minimum [...] to get a window to open"*. Besides, this proposed answer is still missing to call out the core issue (`CreateWindow` presumably never succeeds), and specifically which part solves it.

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is here:

```c
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND hwnd,
        UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam) { }
```

As the compiler warned, this function needs to return a value (but isn't). The behavior of registering this as a window procedure is undefined. It will probably fail to create a window; `CreateWindowEx()` calls into the window procedure with `WM_NCCREATE` and `WM_CREATE` messages before it returns. Either message handler must return a particular value to continue window creation.

There's a similar issue with the window class name: It's using a local variable, but passes a pointer to it out. As `registerWindow()` returns, `CLASS_NAME` is gone. Class registration succeeds, but when it comes time to create the window, the call to `CreateWindowEx()` uses garbage as the window class name.

The first fix is thus:

```c
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND hwnd,
        UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam) {
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

and

```c
void registerWindow(WINDOW *window) {
    static const char CLASS_NAME[] = "Window Class Name";
    // ...
}
```

That solves the window creation, though you won't see the window for long (if at all) because the code immediately falls out of `WinMain()` (which also needs to return a value), causing the process to terminate.

To fix that, you'll have to dispatch messages on the thread that created the window. The following will address both of these issues:

```c
int WINAPI WinMain ( HINSTANCE hInstance,
                        HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                        LPSTR pCmdLine,
                        int nCmdShow ) {
    WINDOW window = {{}, hInstance};
    registerWindow(&window);
    CreateWindow_(&window);
    ShowWindow(window.hwnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg = {0};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

That's the bare minimum required (unless you count `MessageBox()` as *"getting a window to open"*). But it won't allow you to exit the application. To add that functionality, you'll want to add a [`WM_DESTROY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-destroy) handler that will signal the message loop to end, like so:

```c
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc( HWND hwnd,
        UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and for answering the question as it was plainly stated, unfortunately I just passed the return of DefWindowProc from WindowProc in that same way and the only thing that happens now is that the process of the program begins with no Window and does not kill itself unless done so with the task manager, I have also added the message loop as described in an above response and in the official documentation. This was my initial concern as implementation of that before also did not spawn a window, it is not from neglecting official documentation that I've asked this question.

Comment: @woden If you have code that is not behaving like you think it should, then please edit your question to show that code. Not just snippets of code, but a complete [mcve]

Comment: @woden This update fixes the other bug. Mind you, this is literally the minimum required. If you resize the window, it won't render the uncovered area, and the cursor doesn't properly set. Either one is due to the `WNDCLASS` using default values for the background brush and the cursor.